# Can I mock out an Import using ESM and mocha?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

I have something similar to the following

```
import chai from "chai";
import { Thing } from "../src/Thing"

describe("",()=>{
    it("", ()=>{
        chai.assert.equal(Thing.doSomething(), true);
    });
}) 

// Thing.mjs

import { ToMock } from "./Test"

export class Thing {
    static doSomething(){
        ToMock.doSomething();
    }
}
```

So in this case I want to mock `ToMock`. Without doing something super hacky using a constructor...

Is there a way to Mock out an ESM import?

This option does work but is what I am trying to avoid...

```
import chai from "chai";
import { Thing } from "../src/Thing"

describe("",()=>{
    let mock = {
        doSomething: ()=>true;
    }
    let thing = new Thing(mock);
    it("", ()=>{
        chai.assert.equal(thing.doSomething(), true);
    });
}) 

// Thing.mjs
import { ToMock } from "./Test"

export class Thing {
    constructor(mock){
        this.base = mock ? mock : ToMock;
    }
    doSomething(){
        this.base.doSomething();
    }
}
```

This does seem to work but there has to be a better way.